# if has div exists do this else do that with jquery not working

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I have a jquery if else statement, however my if statements works, but my else statement does not.

I converted this original code:

```
$('.pt-trigger').click(function() {
        $pageTrigger = $(this);
        Animate($pageTrigger);
    });
```

Into this(which is where the else statement does not work)

```
$('.pt-trigger').click(function() {
            if ( $(".pt-trigger").has(".tick") ) { 
                $(this).find('.tick').fadeIn(500, function() {
                    setTimeout(function() { 
                        $pageTrigger = $('.pt-trigger');
                        Animate($pageTrigger);
                    },400);
                });
            } 
            else {
                $pageTrigger = $(this);
                Animate($pageTrigger);
            }
    });
```

Here is some of my HTML, one showing with a tick and one without:

```
<div class="pt-trigger-container">
            <button class="pt-trigger" data-animation="1" data-goto="-1">
                Get started
            </button>
        </div>

<div class="pt-trigger-container clearfix">
                <button class="pt-trigger push" data-animation="1" data-goto="-1">
                    Constantly active
                    <div class="tick">
                        <i class="icon-ok-circled2"></i>
                    </div>
                </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both buttons have class `.pt-trigger`, so `$(".pt-trigger").has(".tick")` always returns a set of elements.

Use `$(this)` to check only the clicked button and check the length to see if this set is empty:

```
if ( $(this).has(".tick").length != 0 ) {
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(".pt-trigger")` returns a list of *every* DOM element with `class=pt_trigger`. So `$(".pt-trigger").has(".tick")` isn't a true/false function, it's a *filter* that returns just the ones that have `class=tick` elements inside them.

Unless you're going to be changing which ones have `class=tick` on  the fly, the jQuery way is instead to give each case its own callback:

```
var triggers = $('.pt-trigger');
triggers.has(".tick").click(function() {
    $(this).find('.tick').fadeIn(500, function() {
        setTimeout(function() { 
            $pageTrigger = $('.pt-trigger');
            Animate($pageTrigger);
        },400);
    });
});

triggers.not(triggers.has(".tick")).click(function() {
    $pageTrigger = $(this);
    Animate($pageTrigger);
});
```

Comment: Okay thank you, so how would i edit it into a real if else statment?